# Android how to move the menu item next to cut menu item?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, copy-paste

I am adding a menu item for texts selection. Normally it shows cut, copy, paste, etc. I added a one more item to this menu and named the item as "FORMAT".

For this I added the following code in my Activity Java

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
    //menu.clear();
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.compose, menu);
}
```

I have added the "FORMAT" following by this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/format"
        android:title="FORMAT"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

I am able to get my menu item while long press on texts.. Below is the screen, which reflects my menu item.

[image]

Now I want to move the menu item "FORMAT" to the start of the menu next to the "Cut" menu, but I have got no idea how to do this.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image: enter code here]

Can you please show me an example how I can move the menu "FORMAT" next to "Cut"??

Comment: Maybe something could be done using the `menu` object?